# Stored procedures and error handling

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 10 stored procedures.

For example -

- stored procedure fetches the rows from table A

then stored procedure runs and then third...

How can I do error handling in this.. for example I have to check with if first stored procedure executed successfully run second else throw error. If first executed successfully run second stored procedure if second runs successfully run third otherwise throw error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MASTER_PROCEDURE] AS
EXEC QRY_STEP3
EXEC QRY_STEP_3_1_1
EXEC OQRY_STEP_3_1_1
```

Comment: What do the stored procedures return?  For example, if they result sets, you could check @@Rowcount and if 0, assume the procedure errored out.  depending on what version of SQL you are using, you can also use TRY Catch.   Can you provide your SQL version number and a general idea of what each procedure does or returns?

Comment: They create temp table and temp table created in first stored procedure is used in 2nd stored procedure

Comment: You could check for existence of the temp table before calling the subsequent procedure.   Different ways of doing that, what version of SQL are you using (i.e. run SELECT @@VERSION and see what it returns).

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use @@error.. Can be done like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MASTER_PROCEDURE] AS

EXEC QRY_STEP3 

IF @@error =0

begin

EXEC QRY_STEP_3_1_1 

else

begin

print "error in proc name"

return 1

End 

if (@@error=0) 

Begin

EXEC OQRY_STEP_3_1_1

Else

print "error in proc name"

return 1

End 

END

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add logic to each of your subsidiary stored procedures to determine whether they have succeeded or not. eg test for existence of the temporary table. Then use a return value to indicate success of the proc. Typically this would be 0 for succes and non-zero for failure.

You would then call the procs from your master proc like this

```
DECLARE @ReturnValue INT

EXEC @ReturnValue = QRY_STEP1

IF(@ReturnValue = 0)
BEGIN
    EXEC @ReturnValue = QRY_STEP2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --REPORT ERROR
END
```

Using this approach, your master proc doesnt need to know about the inner workings of each child proc, and your master proc code will be cleaner and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

First to do this correctly you should use TRY CATCH  blocks in the child packages. Those should return to the calling proc if there is an error. This way you can also return an error code to the calling proc if results are unexpected, such as a temp table with zero records which is not an error but which might make the subsequent procs fail.

Next, why are you using child procs at all? Honestly this is something that is probably better done in one proc. You say for instance that you are creating temp tables in one proc that you use in subsequent procs. To do this you need global temp tables. The problem is that global temp tables are not specific to the orginal connection that called them and thus two people trying to do this simluatnaeously might have their data mixedup. Whereas if you use one proc and local temp tables that can't happen.